# parent-child tree in select box

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a tree inside a select box with an unlimited number of parent and children.
and my select box (html part) should be Access and I have given a diagram below.

I have a "categories" array which has two main arrays with an unlimited number of nodes (parent-child). The two main array names are `[scope] => selectboxFirst` and `[scope] => selectboxsecond`. There is a `parentid` which starts with `4000`. I cannot hard code `parentid` in the code. The arrays come from a decoded json string.

I don't know how to loop through this array and show both arrays in a separate select box.

In the example array I have posted, there are two main arrays inside one array but they can also come in other arrays. I don't know how to display this in two select box as parent child.

All the `[scope] => selectboxFirst` categories will display in first select box and `[scope] => selectboxsecond` categories in second select box.

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [message] => Good
            [code] => 200
        )

    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [scope] => selectboxFirst
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4001
                                    [parentId] => 4000
                                    [name] => Access
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4010
                                                    [parentId] => 4001
                                                    [name] => mine
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4011
                                                    [parentId] => 4001
                                                    [name] => yours
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )


                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4002
                                    [parentId] => 4000
                                    [name] => Communication
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4015
                                                    [parentId] => 4002
                                                    [name] => Physician
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 4016
                                                                    [parentId] => 4015
                                                                    [name] => Helps blsys Understand
                                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                                )

                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 4017
                                                                    [parentId] => 4015
                                                                    [name] => Listens
                                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                                )


                                                        )

                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4021
                                                    [parentId] => 4002
                                                    [name] => Clinical ps
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 4022
                                                                    [parentId] => 4021
                                                                    [name] => yours ps/datasssss
                                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                                )



                                                        )

                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4024
                                                    [parentId] => 4002
                                                    [name] => etc
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )



                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4003
                                    [parentId] => 4000
                                    [name] => Office
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4026
                                                    [parentId] => 4003
                                                    [name] => Facilities/Environment
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 4027
                                                                    [parentId] => 4026
                                                                    [name] => Noise
                                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                                )

                                                            [1] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 4028
                                                                    [parentId] => 4026
                                                                    [name] => Lighting
                                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                                )



                                                        )

                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4032
                                                    [parentId] => 4003
                                                    [name] => Office ps
                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [id] => 4033
                                                                    [parentId] => 4032
                                                                    [name] => mine ps
                                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                                )



                                                        )

                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4035
                                                    [parentId] => 4003
                                                    [name] => Billing
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )



                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4004
                                    [parentId] => 4000
                                    [name] => Outgo
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4037
                                                    [parentId] => 4004
                                                    [name] => Diagnosis
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4038
                                                    [parentId] => 4004
                                                    [name] => Quality of Procedure
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4005
                                    [parentId] => 4000
                                    [name] => Loyalty
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4039
                                                    [parentId] => 4005
                                                    [name] => Likely to also
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )



                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [scope] => selectboxSecond
                    [categories] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4251
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Communication with datas
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4262
                                                    [parentId] => 4251
                                                    [name] => respect?
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4263
                                                    [parentId] => 4251
                                                    [name] =>  you?
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )


                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4252
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Communication with Doctors
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4266
                                                    [parentId] => 4252
                                                    [name] => you with courtesy
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )



                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4253
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Responsiveness of data ps
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4269
                                                    [parentId] => 4253
                                                    [name] => During
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4270
                                                    [parentId] => 4253
                                                    [name] => How
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4254
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Pain Management
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4271
                                                    [parentId] => 4254
                                                    [name] => During
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )


                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4255
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Communication about Medicines
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4274
                                                    [parentId] => 4255
                                                    [name] => During this data stay
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4275
                                                    [parentId] => 4255
                                                    [name] => Before giving you
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4276
                                                    [parentId] => 4255
                                                    [name] => Before giving you
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4256
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Discharge Information
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4277
                                                    [parentId] => 4256
                                                    [name] => During this data stay the data?
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4278
                                                    [parentId] => 4256
                                                    [name] => After you left the data
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4279
                                                    [parentId] => 4256
                                                    [name] => During this data stay
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4257
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Care Transition
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4280
                                                    [parentId] => 4257
                                                    [name] => During this data stay
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )


                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4258
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Cleanliness of data Environment
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4282
                                                    [parentId] => 4258
                                                    [name] => During this data?
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4259
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Quietness of data Environment
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4283
                                                    [parentId] => 4259
                                                    [name] => During this data?
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4260
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => also the data
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4284
                                                    [parentId] => 4260
                                                    [name] => Would you?
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4261
                                    [parentId] => 4250
                                    [name] => Overall Rating of data
                                    [children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 4285
                                                    [parentId] => 4261
                                                    [name] => Using any number
                                                    [type] => Reference
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [type] => Reference
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

the output shoiuld be something like for eg: The ids should come inside selectbox along with option
Access

```
Electronics
--Keyboards
--Phones
----HTC DESIRE Z
----HTC ONE X
-------Camera
-------Battety
Food
--Fruits
----Apple
----Watermelon
--Vegetables
----Carrot
----Onion

**inside select box . for eg: <select><option value='4001'>Access</option></select>**
```

I have so far this much but it displays everything .Still not getting

```
$json = json_decode($string,TRUE);


//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($json);

recursive($json,$level=1);
function recursive($array, $level = 1){
    foreach($array as $value){
        //If $value is an array.
        if(is_array($value)){
            //We need to loop through it.
            recursive($value, $level + 1);
        } else{
            //It is not an array, so print it out.
            echo str_repeat("-", $level), $value, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at recursion.

Comment: I don't know my parent id.It can be 2 or 3 any numbers.I got confused how to find the depth without specifying parent_id.

Comment: What structure is supposed to come out of this data structure? A select box can only be a flat list.

Comment: The out put is above .please check it

Comment: I have pated here .  http://pastebin.com/aiQjgg0c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will recurse through your data structure and create the list of options. I will leave the creation of the `select` tag to you, since it is very simple. I've used `PHP_EOL` to add line breaks after each option to make the HTML code easier to read.

```
foreach ($data['categories'] as $c) {
    # scope is $c['scope']
    echo "Starting " . $c['scope'] . PHP_EOL;
    # calling the function on the categories data       
    recurse($c['categories']);
    echo "Finished " . $c['scope'] . PHP_EOL;
}

function recurse($arr, $level = 0){
    # we have a numerically-indexed array. go through each item:
    foreach ($arr as $n) {
        # print out the item ID and the item name
        echo '<option value="' . $n['id'] . '">' 
        . str_repeat("-", $level)
        . $n['name']
        . '</option>'
        . PHP_EOL;
        # if item['children'] is set, we have a nested data structure, so
        # call recurse on it.
        if (isset($n['children'])) {
            # we have children: RECURSE!!
            recurse( $n['children'], $level+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting selectboxFirst
<option value="4001">Access</option>
<option value="4010">-mine</option>
<option value="4011">-yours</option>
<option value="4002">Communication</option>
<option value="4015">-Physician</option>
<option value="4016">--Helps blsys Understand</option>
<option value="4017">--Listens</option>
<option value="4021">-Clinical ps</option>
<option value="4022">--yours ps/datasssss</option>
<option value="4024">-etc</option>
<option value="4003">Office</option>
<option value="4026">-Facilities/Environment</option>
<option value="4027">--Noise</option>
```

(etc.)

You can substitute the appropriate code for "Starting selectboxFirst/selectboxSecond".

Comment: It still displaying as a list, not as in select box.The ids can be shown in the page.Only names to be displayed and ids should be attached inside option as values for eg: <select><option value='4001'>Access</option></select>

Comment: Edit your question to add this info, and you should also have specified that you needed help generating the HTML, too.

Comment: Thanks I have added that I am trying to display <select><option value='4001'>Access</option></select> this way but not getting

Comment: Thanks It seems its working.I will check in detail and let you know the final result soon

Comment: I also found php SPL function RecursiveIterate.Do you think if we use that it will speed up the iteration ,if we have large data

Comment: Not enough to be noticeable. If you're creating a web page, the delay is almost always in how long it takes to send the data to the user, not how long it takes the page to be generated by the server. You can always do some tests to check, of course!